# Assign nil to multiple UIlabels and Uiimageviews at the same time

Tags: swift, xcode

Cant seem to find an answer to this question.

I want to assign the below "UIlabel" and "UIimageview" nil, how would i do this in the same line?

```
productimage.image = nil
producttext.text = nil
```

I've tried the following which doesn't seem to work:

```
productimage.image = producttext.text = nil // this doesnt work

productimage.image = nil, producttext.text = nil // this doesnt work either
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: The way to do this is on two lines. Why would you need to use a single line?

Comment: Use semicolon — productimage.image = nil; producttext.text = nil

Comment: @Chris I have several ones that i need to update and was just wondering if there was a way to make them more compact, else they take up a bunch of space

Comment: @RajaKishan Thanks bro, works like a charm! <3

Comment: @Axxi Ah ok I see. Yeah a semicolon will allow that. I often think it’s less readable though.

Comment: @Chris yeah you're right in that sense, guess ill see what looks best. But now i got both options atleast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use semicolon.

```
productimage.image = nil; producttext.text = nil
```

Comment: This works, but why save a line?  2 lines are easier to read for the next developer.

Comment: @lavta3 OP wants to save line. I know it’s not good way. But have one advantage, this is also useful during debug time when you need to print and execute more than one line. Also, they are many other way for debugging multi line code.